# How to conditionally adjust date on subsequent rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a system that needs to report on the condition of houses. The house fails a housing standard when the it fails a 'primary' element or when it accumulates 2 secondary elements. Here is an example that you could paste into management studio and run - with comments that explain what I am trying to achieve:

```
WITH T1 AS
( SELECT
    1 propertyid,
    'Principal roof covering' text,
    0 isprimary,
    CAST('1 Apr 2016' AS datetime) date,
    'This should not appear because it is secondary and 
    there are no subsequent secondary elements for this property' comment 
    UNION SELECT
    1,
    'Chimney stacks',
    0,
    CAST('1 Apr 2015' AS datetime),
    'This should appear unadjusted because it is secondary and there is a 
    preceding secondary element for the same property' UNION SELECT
    1,
    'Bathroom condition',
    1,
    CAST('1 Apr 2014' AS datetime),
    'This should appear unadjusted because it is primary' UNION SELECT
    2,
    'Damp proof course',
    0,
    CAST('1 Apr 2016' AS datetime),
    'This should not appear because it is secondary and there are no
    subsequent secondary elements for this property' 
    UNION SELECT
    1,
    'External wall finish',
    0,
    CAST('1 Apr 2014' AS datetime),
    'This should get it''s date adjusted to 2015 because it is secondary 
    and the next secondary element is in 2015' UNION SELECT
1,
'Flashings',
0,
CAST('1 Jun 2015' AS datetime),
'This should get it''s date adjusted to Sep 2015 because it is secondary 
    and the next secondary element is in  Sep 2015' UNION SELECT
1,
'Underground drainage',
0,
CAST('1 Sep 2015' AS datetime),
'This should appear unadjusted because it is secondary and there is a 
    preceding secondary element for the same property'
)
SELECT
    *
FROM t1
ORDER BY date
```

How can I filter out secondary elements that don't have a subsequent secondary element and also adjust the date of those that do have a subsequent element to be the date of the subsequent element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should return what you want:

```
WITH T1 AS
( 

    SELECT * 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY propertyid, isprimary ORDER BY date) AS PropNo
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY propertyid, isprimary) AS PropCount
    FROM 
        -- Replace below with your source data table
         (VALUES(1,'Bathroom condition',1,'2014-04-01')
        ,(1,'External wall finish',0,'2014-04-01') 
        ,(1,'Chimney stacks',0,'2015-04-01') 
        ,(1,'Principal roof covering',0,'2016-04-01') 
        ,(2,'Damp proof course',0,'2016-04-01')) T(propertyid, text, isprimary, date)
)
SELECT 
      T1.propertyid
    , T1.text
    , T1.isprimary
    , CASE 
          WHEN T1.isprimary = 1 OR T1.PropNo = T1.PropCount - 1 THEN T1.date
          ELSE ISNULL(T1Next.date, T1.date) END AS [date]
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T1 AS T1Next ON T1.propertyid = T1Next.propertyid 
    AND T1.isprimary = T1Next.isprimary
    AND T1.PropNo = T1Next.PropNo - 1
WHERE T1.isprimary = 1
    OR (T1.PropNo < T1.PropCount)
```

I use the ROW_NUMBER() and COUNT(*) function to determine when there are subsequent rows. To apply the date from the subsequent row, I use a LEFT JOIN.

**EDIT**
Changing the left join to this ensures that the join only occurs on secondary elements and only every second element:

```
LEFT JOIN T1 AS T1Next ON T1.propertyid = T1Next.propertyid 
    AND T1.isprimary = 0
    AND T1Next.isprimary = 0
    AND T1.PropNo = T1Next.PropNo - 1
    AND T1Next.PropNo % 2 = 0
```

That means we don't need the case statement, just this:

```
ISNULL(T1Next.date, T1.date) AS [date]
```

But the where statement is not quite right. This works:

```
WHERE T1.isprimary = 1
    OR (T1.PropNo % 2 = 0)     --every 2nd one
    OR T1Next.date IS NOT NULL --and the 1st if there is a 2nd
```

Comment: Thanks Dan this looks close too, but it is appears to be incorrectly adjusting the date of my "Chimnney Stacks" element in my (revised) test data.

Comment: Working with this I think I've got the solution. I will edit your answer with my changes so that it is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this:

```
    SELECT t1.*
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (t1.isprimary = 1)
            OR (
                t1.isprimary = 0
                AND Post.DATE IS NULL
                )
            THEN T1.DATE
        ELSE Post.DATE
        END AS Date_Corrected
FROM t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) t2.DATE
    FROM T1 t2
    WHERE T2.propertyid = t1.propertyid
        AND t2.DATE > t1.DATE
        AND t2.isprimary = 0
        ORDER BY t2.date
    ) Post
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) t2.DATE
    FROM T1 t2
    WHERE T2.propertyid = t1.propertyid
        AND t2.DATE < t1.DATE
        AND t2.isprimary = 0
        order by t2.date DESC
    ) Pres
ORDER BY t1.DATE
```

Comment: Thank-you. This looks very good but there is an issue when a property fails a 3rd and 4th secondary element. The 3rd element should have it's date moved back to the date of the 4th. See my edit - I'ved added a 3rd and 4th

Comment: please check changed answer

Comment: Now doing the same as Dan's answer - adjusting the "Chimney Stacks" date when it should stay the same.